# Hi, am trying to make a function that returns a sublist from a linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Thanks in Advance.
**am using template class & i get an error saying "Error    C2955 'List': use of class template requires template argument list"**

This is my list Class

```
template <class T>
struct node{
    T Data;
    node<T> * prev;
    node<T> * next;
};

template <class T>
class List
{
public:

    node<T> * front;
    node<T> * rear;

    List();
    virtual ~List();

    bool isEmpty();
    void insertFirst(T Data);
    void insertBack(T Data);

    void insertBefore(node<T> * before, T Data);
    void insertAfter(node<T> * after, T Data);

    int removeFirst();
    int removeLast();

    void removeBefore(node<T> * before);
    void removeAfter(node<T> * after);

    node<T> * find(T Data);
    //void destroy();
    void insertRangeBefore(node<T> * before, List<T> range);
    void insertRangeAfter(node<T> * after, List<T> range);
    void removeRange(node<T> * rangeFirst, node<T> * rangeLast);
    template <class T>
    List getSublist(node<T> * rangeFirst, node<T> * rangeLast);
};
```

**I Want to Create an instance of list and then return the sublist**

```
template<class T>
    List<T> List<T>::getSublist(node<T>* rangeFirst, node<T>* rangeLast) {
        return List();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `List` is a class template. You forgot to supply it's template argument.

Comment: Just like you write `List<T>` in `List<T>::getSublist` `List` and `return List();` need the `<T>`

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. But I suspect that `List` is a template class, and the usage of such a name without a specified template argument is not allowed. Which is what the error message tells you. What is unclear about that?

Comment: yes list is a class template sorry i didnt post that. How do I supply its template argument??

Comment: Do you know how to use templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T>
List<T> List<T>::getSublist(node<T>* rangeFirst, node<T>* rangeLast)
//  ^^^ corrections here
{
    return List();
}
```

The unqualified name of the template (`List`) is equivalent to the fully qualified name (`List<T>`) only inside its definition (and those of its members). However, the return type here is neither, so must be fully qualified.

*Edit* Your header file does actually not declare this member function and your code will still not compile. You must provide a **matching declaration**, i.e.

```
template<class T>
class List 
{
    ...    
    List getSublist(node<T>*, node<T>*);   // not a template
};
```

Your code actually declared a templated member (with another type `T` as template parameter). Just remove the line `template<class T>` from the member declaration.

Btw, you may want to consider having `node` a nested type of `List<T>`. Then you can replace `node<T>` with `node` (almost) everywhere (except when you must qualify it, when it is `List<T>::node` or `typename List<T>::node`).

Comment: i did that and it still has an error saying "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"

Comment: eventhough i already have a matching function declaration in the header file

Comment: No, you do not,

Comment: You're welcome. I'd appreciate if you would accept my answer (click the tick).